# Javascript not calling functions

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

The function called by onLoad is called but stops before calling another function.
I'm sure this is what is happening because I added some debugging `document.write()` functions.

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
function getTemp(){
    document.write("3");//debugging
    $.ajax( {
        type: "GET",
        url: "gettemp.php",
        success:function(data){
            document.write(data);
            document.write("4"); //debugging
        }
    });
}

</script>
</head>
<body onload="onLoad();">
<script>
function onLoad(){
    document.write("1"); //debugging
    getTemp();
    document.write("2"); //debugging
    setInterval(function(){getTemp();}, 10000);
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

It outputs only "1", nothing else. Therefore, I am certain it stops before calling getTemp(). If necessary I will add the php file. As for the split scripts, if you put the onLoad() script in the head script you end up with nothing, not even the "1".

EDIT: Now it gets to "132", but it seems it isn't calling the PHP correctly.

PHP source:

```
<?php
getTemp();
function getTemp()
{
        $filename = "temp";
        $f = fopen($filename,"r");
        $value = fgets($f);
        $value = $value / 100;
        echo $value;
}
?>
```

Comment: what does the console say?

Comment: Are there any console errors?  What happens when you step through the code in the browser's debugger?

Comment: Can you create other functions and see if you can get to them?

Comment: Ehm, considering its run on an apache webserver, nothing. Also, there is nothing in the apache2 log.

Comment: You have an extra brace after the getTemp function declaration. Remove it!

Comment: @user3433131 What do you mean "considering it's run on an Apache webserver, nothing"? The *JavaScript* console. It will *show* you your JS error.

Comment: Remove one of the `}` at the end of `getTemp()`

Comment: Dave: ...there is such a thing? Damn, I suck. How do I access it?

Comment: what browser do you use ?

Comment: Dwza: Firefox, latest version.

Comment: download **[FIREBUG](http://getfirebug.com/)** to see further errors and console if you dont have it. and the the other problem... you open a file and get the first line of it lets say 13200 signs and you devide it with 100... of course you get 132 all the time ^^ what do you expact ?

Comment: Dwza: That's not what's happening. I open the file, get the first line (in this case, 2000), divide it by 100 and print it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

looks like typo

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
function getTemp(){
        document.write("3");//debugging
        $.ajax( {
            type: "GET",
            url: "gettemp.php",
            success:function(data){
                document.write(data);
                document.write("4"); //debugging
            }
        });
    }
// } <-- not needed

</script>
</head>
<body onload="onLoad();">
<script>
function onLoad(){
    document.write("1"); //debugging
    getTemp();
    document.write("2"); //debugging
    setInterval(function(){getTemp();}, 10000);
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

i use `console.log('foobar')` for debugging :)

**EDIT**

Its calling the php correctly...

your problem is your php source... you allways call the same line...

your funaction calls the getTemp and the getTemp allways reads the first line...

take a look at the sample for the **fgets function**

**[SEE SAMPLE FOR fgets](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fgets.php)**

missing a while or any kind of loop and the file length param :D

Comment: That worked. Sort of. Now I'm getting all the way to "132". Looks like it isn't calling the php correctly. Should I make a new issue or continue on this one?

Comment: what is the source of the php, please edit your post

Comment: @user3433131 You should ask a new question; it's now a "How come `echo` isn't writing back to the client?" (Because that's not what echo does.)

Comment: It is the way I do it, I'm using AJAX.

Comment: see my edits. echo is fine but it seems like you missing some in your php file

Comment: It's only supposed to get the first line. Also, after a reboot of the server it works, but it isn't updating. I'll try to work it out on my own.

Comment: @user3433131 if my answere resolved the main problem, except my answere pls :) what is your goal ? i mean reading the first line every second make no real sence for me *gg*

Comment: I've changed my code (not on here). What I am trying to do is have an Arduino read a temperature, send it via USB to a Raspberry Pi, have a Python script catch it and print it in the first line of a file, where the PHP script puts it on the web page. 'nuff said.